# matlab yet another regular expression question

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to match a token, unless it is **exactly** another string:

```
str ='354 : example - asd: 3, test:';
str2='354 : example2 - airplane,';
[~,tok]=regexp(str,'\d+ : (\w+) - (?(~asd)\w+)','match','tokens','once','warnings')
```

I would like to match `airplane` but **not** `asd` but I can't figure out how to make the condition work (example on MathWorks is not very helpful).

Comment: Contrary to what this example might give away, I tried countless permutations, and as anyone knows from working with regex, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement? Why you want to match airplane and why you do not want to match asd?

Comment: I guess I can only elaborate why I opted for tokens, but it's not in-depth, it just seemed like the most straight-forward approach, the rest is just a problem that bugs me and seem to be stuck at. The idea is the regex should match a number of unforeseeable cases, excluding certain few

Comment: Is it possible for you to capture only group ? Following Regex will match the airplane but it also matches other words but first capturing group is airplane and os on. It will skip asd. Have a look, `(?<=example)(?:.*-\s(?!asd))(.*),`

Comment: grouping is fine actually, it would be nice to match both though

Answer (score 0):

`[~,tok]=regexp(str2,'\d+ : (\w+) - (?:asd)*(\w+)*','match','tokens','once','warnings')` this works for me.

please point out if there are flaws or better solutions. thanks @Deep for pointing out the group but not capture possibility